# $ is not defined - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, error-handling

I am new to JQuery and get thefollowing error messages:

```
ERROR: '$' is not defined. [no-undef]
ERROR: 'location' is not defined. [no-undef]
```

For completeness, I have added all the code from the two relevant pages down here.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Fruits Game</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale =1, user-scalable = yes"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>Irrelevant content here</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**jquery.js**

```
var playing = false;

$(function(){
//click on start reset button
    $("#startreset").click(function(){
        //We are playing
        if(playing == true){
            location.reload();
        }else{
            //We are not playing
            playing = true;
        }
    })
});
```

I have tried many solutions from: [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined), yet none seem to solve my problem. Who can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That `[no-undef]` suggests that it's not an error from the browser but rather from whatever compiler or other tool you're using. It doesn't like your `jquery.js` file because you're using variables from elsewhere (`$`) and global variables (`location` - should be `window.location`).

Comment: Your code looks good. I suspect you are not getting these errors in your browser's console, but from your code linter, who has no clue what `$` is at the moment you write your code. It is just a code hint/help.

Comment: Take a look inside this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yeah it probably has something to do with your IDE that does not know about jQuery

Comment: seems you have not loaded the jquery  .. library

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks for the tip

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks the weird thing is that I am working in Brackets and that my JQuery code worked perfectly fine before.

Comment: @scaisEdge havent I loaded jquery with the following code: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: check in your console for error ..  during load .. of these  library  .. (and why you load two library ???)

Comment: Why do you think I load two libraries?

Comment: @scaisEdge it looks like he named the file that holds his code jquery.js and it is not actually the jquery library code.

Comment: I copy-pasted your html and js files in Brackets, and I didn't receive any errors.

Comment: @scaisEdge I didnt get any error in my console btw

Comment: @Tuneer thanks for doing that! Do you think that means I should just ignore these errors?

Comment: https://github.com/you-dont-need-x/you-dont-need-jquery